# How to use a list as a part of arguments for a function?

Tags: functions

I have a function, say `f[x,y,z]` and a list `l={b,c}`. What is a more concise way to write

```
f[a, l[[1]],l[[2]]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`f[a, l[[1]],l[[2]]]` is already concise. You may save a few key strokes using:

```
 f[x, ##] & @@ l
```

> f[x, b, c]

Also

```
f[x, ## & @@ l]
```

> f[x, b, c]

and

```
f[x, Sequence @@ l]
```

> f[x, b, c]

```
f @@ Prepend[l, x]
```

> f[x, b, c]